# Ubuntu 19.04 - Graphical UI does not load automatically

Tags: boot, gnome, graphics, 19.04

I recently upgraded my computer from a  fully functional 18.10 system, to 19.04.

Plymouthd no longer seems to load the boot splash
The graphical UI no longer loads automatically, after staying black it appears to switch to a verbose text console, and it stops there
If I then press <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-F2</kbd>, I get the tty2 text login screen.

Then switch back to the main screen using <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-F1</kbd>, the Gnome UI now loads.

Question what do I need to do to get Gnome to come up to the graphical logon screen after a reboot automatically?

Update:

```
sudo systemctl get-default
graphical.target

 cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="verbose"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the contents of `cat /etc/default/grub`

Comment: Also please include the output of `systemctl get-default`